# View width is not equal to cell width inseide uitable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, autolayout

I am trying to add a view inside a UITableCell.It works fine for all the devices but on iPad the width of view is not equal to cell width.The width of view is half of the width of cell.Please tell me what do here.[image]

Constraints are:

[image]

Comment: how you set view constraints?

Answer (score 0):

please select width and height (any,any) in storyboard.It may be helpful to you.[image]

Comment: which constraints you set of view?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use constrain

First select view which you put on cell and give constrain from 4 side

like below in image

give it top,bottom,left,right = 0

[image]

Comment: i cab't give bottom constraints 0 like that

Comment: than you can give static height or bottom space as you want